# Clarification on Disease and Remove Disease

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, disease

The spell [Remove Disease](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/removeDisease.htm) states:

> Certain special diseases may not be countered by this spell or may be countered only by a caster of a certain level or higher.

I have not yet found any diseases that state that they cannot be cured by said spell. Therefore I am asking for a clarification.

**Is the difference between extraordinary and supernatural diseases connected to Remove Disease's limitation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supernatural diseases are more likely to be resistant to [Remove Disease](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/removeDisease.htm), but not all are.

[Mummy Rot](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/mummy.htm) (scroll down a bit, there isn't an anchor) is a SU disease, which requires a Caster Level of 12 to remove. [Lycanthropy](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/lycanthrope.htm#curingLycanthropy) is a SU disease chich can be cured by Remove Disease at any level, but with a time restriction (within 3 days of contracting the disease). On the other hand, the epic [Hunefer](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/monsters/hunefer.htm) has a SU disease which can be cured by Remove Disease without respect to CL.

Comment: For completion's sake: The spell Scourge (Spell Compendium) inflicts a magical (not SU) disease that may only be healed by *remove disease* after casting a *remove curse* or *break enchantment.*